# React + ES6 + loading component dynamically - Is it a good idea to store component itself in state

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement as shown here (loading components dynamically):

http://blog.netgusto.com/asynchronous-reactjs-component-loading-with-webpack/

I am pretty much successful with the above.  The only concern is about storing the component itself in state.

Is that a good standard i.e., storing component itself in state.  I still wanted to have components to load dynamically.

If storing a component in a state is not a good idea, what would be a better option?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking here - surely the component itself doesn't need to be stored, because the code is the component. Or are you talking about the children?

Comment: If you take a look at the code available at that link, the child component (loaded on demand) is stored in the state.  I am guessing that it was done just to kick-in the render process, again after loading the child component.  If the state is not changed, I think the render does not kick-in or it does not render the newly loaded component.  If my understanding is correct, then is that the good way to do or is there any other better way than storing the child component itself in state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not storing the component inside its own state on that link, 'pulpy' is another object. And I wouldn't see anything wrong with it against the standards or 'not to do's.